# How to find the string between two string with new line char?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a string with new line `\n`, unable to find the string between two different lines.

Eg: `String Name\nString Education\nString Place`

Unable to get String Education using a match or regular expression.

```
test.match(new RegExp("String Name" + "(.*)" + "String Place"));
```

Comment: What is `firstvariable` and `secondvariable`?

Comment: @decpk, It could be string of start and end string, updated now.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex expression should include newline characters.

```
const matches = test.match(new RegExp("String Name" + "\n(.*)\n" + "String Place"));
console.log(matches[1]); // String Education
```